# WCF Service call from IE does not work, but from Chrome it works. Possible Proxy issue?

Tags: .net, wcf, internet-explorer, exception, proxy

We have an ASP.NET application. It calls WCF Services via ScriptManager.AddServiceReference reference from javascript.

Till we have converted the application to work with "Integrated Windows Authentication", everything was great.

But after converting it to "Integrated Windows Authentication" we started to get javascript errors such as:

```
"Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetStockCodeData'. 
 The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because 
 the Message  is empty  (IsEmpty = true). "
```

BTW, WCF calls work perfectly on some clients, but does not work on some other clients.

It is also interesting that when we open Fiddler on the problematic client, things works.

It seems to be a proxy issue, but at the same machine, with the same proxy configurations, some other users can work.

Can you give us some ideas?

Comment: Is it a https call to the WCF service? If you have fiddler up and running with the option to decrypt https traffic it creates some intermediary certificates and hence you would need fiddler to be running for the calls to be succesful. Remove the intermediary certificates from the cert store and you should get it working

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. it is not https traffic. We did not do anything in particular but the issue solved itself. We just enabled and again disabled windows authentication option on IIS and the issue resolved. I think it is flushed the proxy or some kind of things happended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, this is probably related to the issue I discussed over here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-post-bodies-are-zero-bytes-in-length-when-authentication-challenges-are-expected.aspx

The short summary is that if a client browser expects to get an auth challenge, it might omit the POST body on a request (for performance reasons) until the server issues an authentication challenge.

Comment: Thank you EricLaw. I think our problem was probably related about what you sent.